# Reset Akka actors to initial state

Tags: scala, akka, state, reset, actor

I have actors that do a simulation, and then send back data. I would like to be able to run the simulation multiple times, so I need to reset the internal states of each actor.

How can I reset the internal state of an actor, so that that it has the same state as when I created it?

Comment: Why not use `become`? There are a lot examples over the net

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it

## Manual resetting

Handle a message called as `reset` and re-initialize all the actor state by yourself manually.

Here is the code sample which handles reset string message and resets the state of the actor.

```
class FooActor extends Actor {
  var maybeBars: Option[ActorRef] = _
  def receive = {
    case "foo" => println("foo")
    case "reset" => maybeBars = _
  }
}
```

## Automatic resetting

Second way is to throw an exception in the actor and kill the actor. In this case akka default supervisor strategy will restart the actor with initial empty state.

```
class FooActor extends Actor {
  var maybeBars: Option[ActorRef] = _
  def receive = {
    case "foo" => println("foo")
    case "reset" => throw new Exception("reset")
  }
}
```